# Splitting lines in a file into string and hex and do operations on the hex values

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a large file with several lines as given below.I want to read in only those lines which have the _INIT pattern in them and then strip off the _INIT from the name and only save the OSD_MODE_15_H part in a variable. Then I need to read the corresponding hex value, 8'h00 in this case, ans strip off the 8'h from it and replace it with a 0x and save in a variable.
I have been trying strip the off the _INIT,the spaces and the = and the code is becoming really messy.

```
localparam OSD_MODE_15_H_ADDR = 16'h038d;
localparam OSD_MODE_15_H_INIT = 8'h00
```

Can you suggest a lean and clean method to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried using regular expressions or manually stripped the parts with "asfd".replace() and friends?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following solution uses a regular expression (compiled to speed searching up) to match the relevant lines and extract the needed information. The expression uses named groups "id" and "hexValue" to identify the data we want to extract from the matching line.

```
import re

expression = "(?P<id>\w+?)_INIT\s*?=.*?'h(?P<hexValue>[0-9a-fA-F]*)"
regex = re.compile(expression)

def getIdAndValueFromInitLine(line):
  mm = regex.search(line)
  if mm == None:
    return None # Not the ..._INIT parameter or line was empty or other mismatch happened
  else:
    return (mm.groupdict()["id"], "0x" + mm.groupdict()["hexValue"])
```

EDIT: If I understood the next task correctly, you need to find the hexvalues of those INIT and ADDR lines whose IDs match and make a dictionary of the INIT hexvalue to the ADDR hexvalue.

```
regex = "(?P<init_id>\w+?)_INIT\s*?=.*?'h(?P<initValue>[0-9a-fA-F]*)"
init_dict = {}
for x in re.findall(regex, lines):
    init_dict[x.groupdict()["init_id"]] = "0x" + x.groupdict()["initValue"]

regex = "(?P<addr_id>\w+?)_ADDR\s*?=.*?'h(?P<addrValue>[0-9a-fA-F]*)"
addr_dict = {}
for y in re.findall(regex, lines):
    addr_dict[y.groupdict()["addr_id"]] = "0x" + y.groupdict()["addrValue"]

init_to_addr_hexvalue_dict = {init_dict[x] : addr_dict[x] for x in init_dict.keys() if x in addr_dict}
```

Even if this is not what you actually need, having init and addr dictionaries might help to achieve your goal easier. If there are several _INIT (or _ADDR) lines with the same ID and different hexvalues then the above  dict approach will not work in a straight forward way.

Comment: Your final capture would contain the semicolon from the first line in the example. 
Also, I think that named capture groups help a lot in keeping a regex readable.

Comment: Edited the code to include only hex digits in the last group.

Comment: you're matching the localparam part of the line in the first group

Comment: Thanks, fixed. Actually ran the code this time and checked that it works.

Comment: @astraujums thanks so much! I can use id and hexvalue as key value pairs for the dictionary right?

Comment: @serendipity "id" and "hexValue" were names of the groups in the regular expression. The groupdict() method of the match object returns a dictionary where these names are keys while the values are strings that matched the corresponding named groups.

Comment: @astraujums So now following your method I have two dictionaries...one for the _INIT with init_id and init_hexvalue as keys and one for _ADDR with addr_id and addr_hexvalues as keys. What i do next is to compare the id's for init and addr and if the id's match then just take the init_hexvalue and addr_hexvalue and put them in a new dictionary.This creation of new dictionary is where I am getting stuck at.Attaching some piece of code below:

Comment: `regex = "(?P<init_id>\w+?)_INIT\s*?=.*?'h(?P<initValue>[0-9a-fA-F]*)"`
`for x in re.findall(regex, lines):`
 `init_list = (x.groupdict()["init_id"], "0x" + x.groupdict()["initValue"])`

`regex = "(?P<addr_id>\w+?)_ADDR\s*?=.*?'h(?P<addrValue>[0-9a-fA-F]*)"`
`for y in re.findall(regex, lines):`
 `addr_list = (y.groupdict()["addr_id"], "0x" + y.groupdict()["addrValue"])`

`for key in set(init_list['init_id'].keys()).union(addr_list['addr_id'].keys()):`
        `if init_list[key] == addr_list[key]`
 `expect_by_addr = dict (addr_list['addrValue']....something`

Comment: I edited the answer to give a possible solution to your next task with the condition that I understood it properly.

Answer (score 1):

try something like this- not sure what all your requirements are but this should get you close:

```
with open(someFile, 'r') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        if '_INIT' in line:
            apostropheIndex = line.find("'h")
            clean_hex = '0x' + line[apostropheIndex + 2:]
```

In the case of "16'h038d;", clean_hex would be "0x038d;" (need to remove the ";" somehow) and in the case of "8'h00", clean_hex would be "0x00"

Edit: if you want to guard against characters like ";" you could do this and test if a character is alphanumeric:

```
clean_hex = '0x' + ''.join([s for s in line[apostropheIndex + 2:] if s.isalnum()])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression and the `re.findall()` function. For example, to generate a list of tuples with the data you want just try:

```
import re
lines = open("your_file").read()
regex = "([\w]+?)_INIT\s*=\s*\d+'h([\da-fA-F]*)"
res = [(x[0], "0x"+x[1]) for x in re.findall(regex, lines)]
print res
```

The regular expression is very specific for your input example. If the other lines in the file are slightly different you may need to change it a bit.